# UITextField clearButtonMode and UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an extended UITextField (added a NSString property, inputType to it) to take in user input. when the user tap's the text field, i use a picker for the user to select the input. i also need to allow the user to clear the text box so i thought i could use

```
tillageTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

to clear the text field.

the issue is when you tap the X to clear the text box, it also fires my picker. i use:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(MyTextField *) textField 
{
    //other code
    else if ([textField.inputType isEqualToString:@"tillageMethod"])
    {
        self.customArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"No Till", @"Strip Till", @"Full Till", nil];
        self.tempTextField = textField;
        [self showPicker];

        return  NO;
    }
    //other code
}
```

to show the picker.

is there a way for me to tell if the user tapped the clear button and not show the picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also implement `textFieldShouldClear:` and set a flag on your class (e.g. `doNotShowPickerOnNextCallback`)

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {

    if ([textField.inputType isEqualToString:@"tillageMethod"]) {

        if (![self pickerIsShowing]) {
            self.doNotShowPickerOnNextCallback = YES;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    //other code
    else if ([textField.inputType isEqualToString:@"tillageMethod"]) {

        if (self.doNotShowPickerOnNextCallback) {

            self.doNotShowPickerOnNextCallback = NO;
            return NO;
        }

        self.customArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"No Till", @"Strip Till", @"Full Till", nil];
        self.tempTextField = textField;
        [self showPicker];

        return  NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: this would allow me to clear it w/out the picker showing, but would not allow the user to change his selection.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that? The picker will show providing the user hasn't *just* cleared the text field.

Comment: In fact, I've made a slight amendment to avoid the picker refusing to show if the text field is cleared while the picker is visible, but otherwise this should work fine.

Comment: yep, you are correct. this works like a charm. i guess the first time i read through it i thought it would not allow the picker to show again regardless of where it was tapped. thanks a lot for the help!